# register has type Long (High Half) but expected Long (Low Half)

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali

I'm trying to fix a problem with Media Player seekTo() method which is called on a Forward/Rewind remote button press event, but I'm getting this error:
[image: bug_report]
with the following edited smali trying to convert long parameter to int:

```
.method private static synthetic a(JLandroid/media/MediaPlayer;)V
    .locals 1

    long-to-int v0, p1
    .line 317
    invoke-virtual {p2, v0}, Landroid/media/MediaPlayer;->seekTo(I)V

    return-void
.end method
```

How can I fix the error or is there any other way to make it work?

This is the original code (but when I press Forward or Rewind it just stops/pauses the video):

```
long-to-int p1, p0
.line 317
invoke-virtual {p2, p1}, Landroid/media/MediaPlayer;->seekTo(I)V
```

My temporary fix was this:

```
.method private static synthetic a(JLandroid/media/MediaPlayer;)V
    .locals 3

#get current position
invoke-virtual {p2}, Landroid/media/MediaPlayer;->getCurrentPosition()I
move-result v0

#add some ms to current position register
const/16 v1, 0x6978
add-int v2,v0,v1
add-int v2,v2,v1
add-int v2,v2,v1
add-int v2,v2,v1
add-int v2,v2,v1

#seek to calculated position
    .line 317
    invoke-virtual {p2, v2}, Landroid/media/MediaPlayer;->seekTo(I)V
    return-void
.end method
```

But it only seeks Forward even when I press Rewind (because I only add time to current position).
I couldn't find/create custom method for Rewind event, source is quite large and obfuscated.
Following the chain of error and chain of method call didn't lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a static method, there is no implicit "this" argument, and the parameter registers start at `p0`. So the first long argument is `p0`,`p1`, and the `MediaPlayer` argument is `p2`.

For the `long-to-int` instruction (and most instructions that work with long values), you specify the wide value for it to work on by passing the first register in the wide register pair. In this case, that is `p0`, not `p1`.

The error is referring to the fact that you're passing the upper half of the wide register pair, instead of the lower half.

So, `long-to-int v0, p0` is probably what you want.

Comment: Thnx for your explanation, I couldn't find any related information online. Even though it didn't resolve my issue it helped me understand its structure. I think the problem is in the parameter which is being sent.

Comment: Yeah, It didn't seem like your changes were actually... changing anything :)